# solving set a set of in-equations for x and y

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, non-convex-optimization

I have a set of below in-equations. Can we solve  for a solution of x and y

$$x>2$$
$$xy>5$$
$$y^2x\leq9$$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

From the second inequality we find that $y>0$. The last two inequalities implies that $\frac{5}{x}<y\leq \frac{9}{x^2}$, which is possible only when $x\geq\frac{25}{9}$. My idea is from the method of “combination of calculation and graph” which I used a lot in high school. Ross Millikan just took this way to solve your problem. And I really recommend this method.

Comment: what if I say the range of x is between 0 and 1

Comment: correction: last equation is square(y) *x<=9

Comment: Note that OP has changed the last equation, rendering our answers obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

If you plot the curves of equality you get a graph like the below.  The blue is $xy=5$ and the orange is $xy^2=9$.  We want the space on or below the orange, above the blue, and right of $x=2$.  We can find the crossing point by solving the equalities simultaneously.
$$xy=5\\ xy^2=9  \\ y=\frac 95  \\x=\frac {25}9$$
The infinite region between the curves and right of the crossing point is acceptable.

[image]

Comment: what if the range of x is between 0 and 1.

Comment: No, in that case $x^2y=99,$ which is greater than $9$.  Not even close.

Comment: correction:
last equation is square(y) *x<=9